# es failed to write index state,caused by Underlying file changed by an external force

Tags: elasticsearch

I deleted all files accidentally in `/home/plog/elk/data/elasticsearch-data` path,and then es's healthy status is shown in `red`.
I restart the es daemons and the log shows cannot find file `/home/plog/elk/data/elasticsearch-data/nodes/0/node.lock`.
And then, I start es on each server separately which can generate node.lock automatically.The problem of cannot find file has been solved.
But, es's healthy status is still shown in `red`. The log shows `failed to write index state` ,caused by `Underlying file changed by an external force`.
How can I solve this problem
The error log is as follows:

```
[2019-03-25T10:23:32,610][WARN ][o.e.g.MetaStateService   ] [es] [[test_2019.03.10/L3uPPm-vSSW_aG6Qvzih5A]]: failed to write index state
org.apache.lucene.store.AlreadyClosedException: Underlying file changed by an external force at 2019-03-25T02:03:45.489478Z, (lock=NativeFSLock(path=/home/plog/elk/data/elasticsearch-data/nodes/0/node.lock,impl=sun.nio.ch.FileLockImpl[0:9223372036854775807 exclusive valid],creationTime=2019-02-27T08:51:35.409994Z))
    at org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory$NativeFSLock.ensureValid(NativeFSLockFactory.java:191) ~[lucene-core-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0 b5bf70b7e32d7ddd9742cc821d471c5fabd4e3df - jimczi - 2018-09-18 13:01:13]
    at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.assertEnvIsLocked(NodeEnvironment.java:999) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.indexPaths(NodeEnvironment.java:798) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.gateway.MetaStateService.writeIndex(MetaStateService.java:124) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.gateway.GatewayMetaState.applyClusterState(GatewayMetaState.java:173) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.ClusterApplierService.lambda$callClusterStateAppliers$6(ClusterApplierService.java:481) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) [?:1.8.0_202]
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.ClusterApplierService.callClusterStateAppliers(ClusterApplierService.java:478) [elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.ClusterApplierService.applyChanges(ClusterApplierService.java:465) [elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.ClusterApplierService.runTask(ClusterApplierService.java:416) [elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.ClusterApplierService$UpdateTask.run(ClusterApplierService.java:160) [elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:624) [elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.runAndClean(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:244) [elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.run(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:207) [elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_202]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_202]
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved.I deleted all the indexes, then deleted the nodes folder and started again.
Check out this blog post: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/distress-elasticsearch-does-not-start/152288